# Teamcity snapshot dependency based on trigger

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

So i have several parts to this project -  one of which is an opencv build which can take some time. I've made another build dependent on this as a snapshot build with the setting "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one".

The opencv build is only triggered on commits to the relevant directory (using build triggers)
And my other build is set up similarly (based on another folder)

BUT as they are both from the same repository, the trigger of one causes a trigger of the other. It seems that 'suitable' does not consider build triggers, but only commit number. Is there any way to set this up so that the dependent build will not be rebuilt every time and only when it would trigger anyway (i still need the dependency between both)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the checkout rules for the opencv build.

```
Edit configuration
Go under '2. Version Control Settings'
Under the VCS root 'Edit Checkout Rules'
Add the rule so it only considers what affects it (e.g. +:\Repo\opencv)
```

It will then only be triggered when there is a change in this folder.

Comment: got error: Failed to perform checkout on agent: Agent checkout for the git supports only include rule of form '. => subdir'

Comment: seems git cannot do a subdir checkout so this approach won't work?